# Apache Thrift encryption - Java

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol, libsodium

I plan to use Thrift for Client/Server RPCs, and I would like to encrypt the exchanged data using libsodium.
I know there is TLS builtin but the TLSTransportParameters do not seem to give much configuration possibilities.

Does someone know at which points i would have to extend thrift to enable this?

Comment: It may be a good idea to ask this question in the Thrift user mailing list, or even on freenode #thrift channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My firm created a custom Camellia transport layer for use with thrift. By creating a layered transport we were able to insert the cipher in between the enpoint transport (TSocket, TPipe, etc.) and the serialization protocol (TBinaryProtocol or what have you). This required 0 modifications to Thrift and was easy to port to the languages we used (C++, Java, Python). It also allowed us to add other standard transport layers to the stack when needed (e.g. TFramedTransport).

To build such a layered transport you simply expose TTransport to the layer above, and consume TTransport from the layer below. TTransport consists of the typical unix file methods: open, close, read and write, with the addition of the important flush() method which signals the message is complete and should be sent to the end point.

Thrift has a pretty nice architecture for making such extensions, so there are other choices you could make but I think that for message encryption often the transport layer is the right place to look. By placing your cipher just above the end point transport (TSocket, etc.) you will encrypt everything in the TCP payload.

Comment: Is the Camellia transport layer open source?

Comment: There are several Camellia implementations available as open source, here's a good link: https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/source.html   The listings are in C, Java, Python among others. You will need to add a mode to the block cipher for streaming. My firm's Apache Thrift transport layer implementation is not public.

Comment: The contents of the request/response are then buffered in the tranport layer and then encrypted before being sent? Did i understand correctly that an own implementation of TSocket is used for the encryption layer purpose or is there other aspects to take into consideration?

Comment: Thrift supports two types of transports, End Point and Layered. End Point Transports do I/O  outside of Thrift. For example TSocket does socket I/O and TSimpleFileTransport does file I/O. Layered transports can be stacked on top of end points, and you can have multiple layers in most language implementations. This means that you can create a TCipherTransport as a layered transport and place it anywhere in the transport stack above the end point. For example you could create an I/O stack which might look something like this: TBinaryProtocol/TFramedTransport/TCipherTransport/TSocket